# Failing to install pyodbc package in AWS ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, pyodbc

I'm running a basic Amazon Linux AMI VM and trying to set a Python script to run remotely. I have most of the stuff set up, however I can't get pyodbc to install using pip or any other method I've been able to find. It might be missing a dependency or something but it just says, "Failed building wheel for pyodbc". I'm using this to connect to an RDS SQL server database. Any advice on how to get pyodbc working, or on an alternative package to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: People will be unable to help without seeing the full error output.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZxCaX17

I've included screenshots of the full error output here.

Comment: Says you're missing gcc, install that.

Comment: I got a different error now, smells like progress. Now it says, 
"gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: no such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I tried running the same sudo yum install command to grab cc1plus or execvp but no such thing exists. So I'm back to scratching my head wondering what exactly it wants.

Comment: I think g++ is the package you need for cc1plus.

Comment: I googled it and it seems like you're correct, however "sudo yum install g++" just returns "No package g++ available"

Comment: i believe build-essential would work for your case.

Comment: @matesio build-essential is a debian thing. OP is on amazon linux (RHEL based)

Comment: @jordanm, for Amazon linux it should be gcc72 gcc72-c++

Comment: @WestonSapusek I have run into similar issue where i cant pip install pyodbc on aws linux2 instance. Can you share what you did?